# Найти в строке слова, состоящие из разных букв. Выдаёт ошибку. Пример ввода: ffff ghytr. вывод: ghytr

Tags: c, поиск

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//Найти в строке слова, состоящие из разных букв.

char *far (char *s)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int len=0;
    int i=0;
    char *res=calloc(strlen(s)+1, sizeof(char));
    while (s[i] == ' ')
        { ++i; }
    while (s[i])
        {
            int j=i;
            while( s[j] != ' ')
            {
                j++;
                if (s[i] != s[j])
                    {flag = 1;}
            }
            if (flag == 1)
                {
                   strncat (res, &s[i], j-i);
                   strncat(res, " ", 1);
                }
                  len+= j-i;
            while (s[j] == ' ') { ++j; }
            i=j;
        }
    res = (char*)realloc(res, len + 1);
    res[len] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int main()
{
  char *s[203];
  char *res = NULL;
  scanf("%200[^\n]s" , s);
  res = far(s);

   printf("%s", res);
   free(res);
   res = NULL;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас тут слишком много ошибок... Наиболее очевидные:

1)

```
char *s[203];
      scanf("%200[^\n]s" , s);
```

Здесь символ '*' в описании строки совершенно лишний.

2)

```
while( s[j] != ' ')
    {
         j++;
            if (s[i] != s[j])
            {flag = 1;}
    }
```

Здесь Вы сравниваете очередной символ слова **только** с первым символом, а не со всеми символами попарно.

В качестве рекомендации: есть такое правило в программировании: каждая функция должна выполнять только **одно** действие. Ваша функция *far()* выполняет **два** действия:

1. Выделение слова
2. Проверка повторяемости символов

Поэтому рекомендую Вам организовать в функции *main()* цикл перебора слов в строке, внутри которого будут вызываться **две** функции - выделения и проверки.

Answer (score 0):

Исправленное и рабочее(возможно не самое эффективное):

```
            char *far (char *s)
            {
                 int len=0, i=0;
                char *res=calloc(strlen(s)+1, sizeof(char));
                while (s[i] == ' ')
                    { ++i; }
                    int flag=0;
                while (s[i])
                    {
                        int j=i;
                        while( s[j] != ' ' &&s[j] != '\0')
                        {
                            if (s[i] != s[j])
                                {flag = 1;}
                                j++;
                        }
                        if (flag == 1)
                            {
                               strncat (res, &s[i], j-i);
                               len+= j-i;
                               len++;
                               strncat(res, " ", 1);
                               flag=0;
                            }
                            while (s[j] == ' ') { ++j; }
                            i=j;
                    }
                res = realloc(res, len + 1);
                res[len] = '\0';
                return res;
            }

            int main()
            {
                int w_continue=1;
                while (w_continue)
                {
              char s[203];
              char *res = NULL;
              scanf("%200[^\n]s" , s);
              res = far(s);
               printf("%s", res);
               if(*res==NULL)
               {
                   printf("no words with different letters");
               }
               free(res);
               res = NULL;
               printf("\nIf you want to stop-press 0\n");
               scanf("%d", &w_continue);
                }

                return 5;
            }
```